# File not found error on gitlab server, even when file is present

Tags: python, makefile, gitlab, git-lfs, file-not-found

[The error you can see file not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZooZX.png)File not found an error on GitLab when converted to large file system LFS. The file is present on GitLab server and I can download it is perfect. But when I tried to run make a test on the GitLab server it gives me such an error.
Sorry, I'm new to this, I am sorry if I could not frame the question in a proper format.
[The file is present in the repository and it opened and works fine when downloaded, only the make test does not run on server. Make test runs fine on local machine. I think it is something related to LFS. Idk but](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9yeD.png)
[Link to error on gitlab](https://gitlab.informatik.uni-bremen.de/cgvr/smida2/schau_mir_in_die_augen/-/jobs/314106)

[Link to file which is present but still error occurs](https://gitlab.informatik.uni-bremen.de/cgvr/smida2/data_gaze_on_faces/-/blob/master/observer_info_cleaned_378.csv)

Comment: Please include your output directly in question. Those URLs are not public and cannot be consulted without having an account (and probably appropriate permissions).

Comment: Hello, I have added image, Please help. It would be really appreciated.